# How to start postgres in a docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I run postgres in docker with the following command:

```
docker run --name postgres-ssl --network=host -e POSTGRES_DB=smmjaipgdb -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=smmJAIpgpassword -e POSTGRES_USER=smmjaipguser -p 5432:5432 -v /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -v /home/mvp_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/ssl  postgres:11 -c ssl=on -c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.cer -c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.key
```

I put certificate and key in appropriate place, and set root as owner of the key with permissions:

```
chown 0 server.key & chmod 600 server.key
```

I run the docker and got the error:

```
could not load private key file "/var/lib/postgresql/ssl/server.key": Permission denied
```

Could you help me run postgres succesfully!
What i have done wrong?

Comment: you migth read [that example of docker file](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/bb0d97951918e6d281f510adb3896da433a52bc4/13/alpine/Dockerfile) ; study it & then adapt to feet your need .

Answer (score 2):

1. Pull down the latest stable release or the version of your choice of the Postgres image from docker hub.

> ```
> docker pull postgres:[tag_you_want]
> ```

2. Create a Directory to Serve as the Local Host Mount Point for Postgres Data Files

> If you want to persist data generated by the Postgres instance running inside a container beyond the container’s lifecycle, you need to map a local mount point as a data volume to an appropriate path inside the container.
>
> ```
> mkdir -p $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres
> ```

3. Run the Postgres Container

> Starting the Postgres container is as simple as running the docker run command.
>
> ```
> docker run --rm   --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data  postgres
> ```

4. Connect to Postgres

> ```
> psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres
> ```

**For more information on this, follow [this](https://hackernoon.com/dont-install-postgres-docker-pull-postgres-bee20e200198) link.**